# compare subset column of current i and subset column of next i in R for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing, try-catch

I am a Python user, and am fairly new to R. I am trying to pass two subsets of a df to a pearson_def function in order to calculate the correlation between the two. Please find the first 100 rows of the tibble below:

```
[texas_biz1:100c("countyfips", "merchants_all") <- tibble::tibble(
  countyfips = c(48001, 48003, 48005, 48007, 48013, 48015, 48019, 48021, 48025, 
    48027, 48029, 48031, 48035, 48037, 48039, 48041, 48043, 48049, 
    48051, 48053, 48055, 48057, 48061, 48063, 48067, 48071, 48073, 
    48085, 48089, 48091, 48093, 48097, 48099, 48113, 48121, 48123, 
    48133, 48135, 48139, 48141, 48143, 48145, 48147, 48149, 48157, 
    48161, 48163, 48165, 48167, 48171, 48181, 48183, 48185, 48187, 
    48189, 48193, 48199, 48201, 48203, 48209, 48213, 48215, 48217, 
    48219, 48221, 48223, 48225, 48227, 48231, 48233, 48237, 48239, 
    48241, 48245, 48249, 48251, 48255, 48257, 48259, 48265, 48273, 
    48277, 48281, 48285, 48287, 48289, 48291, 48293, 48299, 48303, 
    48307, 48309, 48321, 48323, 48325, 48329, 48331, 48337, 48339, 
    48341),
  merchants_all = c(-0.214, -0.125, -0.324, -0.614, -0.361, -0.3, -0.0265, -0.289, 
    -0.398, -0.293, -0.375, -0.52, -0.414, -0.275, -0.368, -0.282, 
    -0.31, -0.368, -0.261, -0.228, -0.412, -0.217, -0.273, -0.49, 
    -0.0355, -0.064, -0.245, -0.214, -0.2, -0.16, -0.431, -0.394, 
    -0.351, -0.22, -0.313, -0.194, -0.566, -0.376, -0.241, -0.258, 
    -0.255, 0.251, -0.295, -0.276, -0.348, -0.318, -0.26, -0.379, 
    -0.37, -0.318, -0.278, -0.234, -0.352, -0.34, -0.195, -0.162, 
    -0.396, -0.362, -0.241, -0.325, -0.172, -0.246, -0.109, -0.312, 
    -0.26, -0.163, -0.125, -0.405, -0.237, -0.0109, -0.358, -0.533, 
    -0.34, -0.292, -0.171, -0.227, -0.273, -0.278, -0.344, -0.188, 
    -0.457, -0.21, -0.374, -0.39, -0.162, -0.371, -0.231, -0.019, 
    0.00933, -0.291, -0.307, -0.226, -0.408, -0.343, -0.343, -0.306, 
    0.223, -0.45, -0.242, -0.251)
)
```

I am trying to subset the df by county, then take the rows from the current county iteration of merchants_all and the rows from the next county iteration of merchants_all and test for correlation between the two times series using pearson's r. Please find what I've tried below:

```
lst <- list(unique(texas_biz$countyfips))
for(i in 1:length(lst)) {
obj <- tryCatch({
x <- lst[[i]]
a <- texas_biz[which(texas_biz$countyfips %in% x),]
y <- lst[[i+1]]
y <- ifelse(is.null(y), NA, y)
b <- texas_biz[which(texas_biz$countyfips %in% y),]
if (length(a$merchants_all == b$merchants_all)) {
print(pearson_def(a$merchants_all, b$merchants_all)) }
else {
print(length(a$merchants_all), length(b$merchants_all))
}
}, error = function(e) NA)
print(obj)
    }
```

I'm getting just a print out of NA, which I assume occurs as the loop attempts to index outside of the list(unique(texas_biz$countyfips)) list. I've tried to implement a tryCatch but I must be doing something wrong... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Please find the helper functions being used in the loop below:

```
average <- function(x) { # x is a numeric vector
    mean(x)
}
pearson_def <- function(x, y) {
    n = length(x)
    # insert a check for equivalence of length between x and y in R
    avg_x <- average(x)
    avg_y <- average(y)
    diffprod <- 0
    xdiff2 <- 0
    ydiff2 <- 0
    for(i in 1:n) {
        xdiff <- x[i] - avg_x
        ydiff <- y[i] - avg_y
        diffprod <- diffprod + (xdiff * ydiff)
        xdiff2 = xdiff2 + (xdiff * xdiff)
        ydiff2 = ydiff2 + (ydiff * ydiff)
        }
    diffprod / sqrt(xdiff2 * ydiff2)
    }
```

Thank you!